# javascript show hide div onload dynamically

Tags: javascript

I want to use a javascript loop to check if a div exists and if it does show it onload. I have been tasked with this but am very much a novice when it comes to javascript.

Here is my javascript:

```
function createtitleid() {
    var div_title = [];
    for (i = 1; i < 10;) {
        var title = 'div_title' + i;
        if (document.getElementById(title)) {
            document.getElementById(title).style.display = "block";
        }
        i++;
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<div style="color:navy; font-size:25px; line-height:31px; font-weight:bold;" id="div_title1">Text
</div>
```

I have added the createtitleid function to the onload statement.

Right now nothing happens, but when I check the console there are no errors. The final page will have anywhere between 1 and 10 divs with an id using the naming convention of div_title and the number. The script should check to see if the div id exists and if so show the title. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So what is the problem?

Comment: It's not clear what problem you're having, although at first glance it doesn't look like the code would do what I suspect you want it to.  What happens when you run this?  What would you prefer?

Comment: Judging by the code you're showing, the `div` will always be visible, unless you have some CSS that you haven't shown that sets `display: none`. Even after adding `display: none`, your code seems to work fine: http://jsfiddle.net/vncj2uce/. Granted, I was not able to use `onload` as I couldn't modify the `body` tag in JSFiddle, but the effect should be the same.

Comment: Are you calling `createtitleid` when `onload` is fired?

Comment: That's an interesting way to write a for loop. `for (i = 1; i < 10;) { ...; i++}`

Comment: This isn't your bug, but a class might be a better choice than ids, here.

Comment: Thanks for all your help. @JackieChiles - you were right on point...I totally missed the css. I can't believe it. As usual, I missed something completely simple.